# Should I allow my cpu to go 100% in a web server fine tuning?

Tags: python, performance, load, webserver

I am configuring a python server. I am playing with the number of python processes. Should I set the number of processes that will let go all the cores to 100% in case of high load or should I limit the number of processes to a lower number to avoid all the cores to reach 100%? What is the best practice?

PS: The server runs on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this depends heavily on how long you intend on allowing your CPUs to clock 100%, and what kind of processor you have. If you have a good CPU (i5 or i7) then you can go up to five or six hours with your CPU maintaining good performance. If you have a lower end processor, I do not recommend allowing it to go at 100% for more than a couple of hours.

There is a process called overclocking if you wish to enable that for short periods of time. 
http://lifehacker.com/a-beginners-introduction-to-overclocking-your-intel-pr-5580998

Finally, what you need to be on the lookout for is not your CPU level--if you have a decent CPU (anywhere from i3 up) it is likely that it can take the pressure. What you should be concerned about, however, is the heat output. Constantly monitor your computer's temperature, and  make sure that it is well ventilated and the fans are functional.

There is a very good chance that your computer will have to run processes to the point where it is clocking in 90% and up, so I would recommend enabling whatever number of processes will cause that CPU pressure. You should be prepared for any possible scenarios!

Best of luck!

Comment: The server runs in the cloud so I do not care of the heat.

Comment: @poiuytrez sorry about that XD my home server runs directly from one of my desktops so it is prone to overheating.